# (Play framework) Setting initial data yaml on an @OrderColumn

Tags: java, jpa, playframework

I can't seem to get the data to populate the ordering column on a play bootstrap with my initial-data yaml file. It just shows as null values on the column it creates named "entries_ORDER".

In my yaml file I have tried 'entries: 0' and 'entries_ORDER: 0' with no luck.

Group.java

```
public class ContactGroup extends Model {
    @Required
    public String title;

    public boolean showTitle = false;

    public boolean isDefault = false;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="group", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    @OrderColumn
    public List<ContactEntry> entries;
}
```

initial-data.yml

```
# Contact Group
ContactGroup(group1):
    isDefault: 1
    showTitle: 1
    title: My Title

# Contact Entry
ContactEntry(entry1):
    title: Entry Title 1
    group: [group1]
    entries_ORDER: 0

ContactEntry(entry2):
    title: Entry Title 2
    group: [group1]
    entries_ORDER: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working.

I had to tell the @OrderColumn to use a field set by me, rather than letting it create the column itself.

I created the below on my ContactEntry model:

```
public Integer entries_order;
```

then gave the @OrderColumn in my ContactGroup model the name of that Integer:

```
@OrderColumn(name="entries_order")
```

I then just had to use that with my yaml:

```
entries_order: 3
```